# how to enable or disable application for a specific user using IBM mobile first platform

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security, device-management

I need to disable an application for some users, which can be done using worklight console i guess . But need to know the procedure to achieve the same.
any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the user documentation topic for the feature you are talking about: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_device_mgmt.html?lang=en

Stack Overflow is fro technical/programming Questions and Answers.